# How to make the html input field allow to be blank, when i click the button?

Tags: html, asp.net

How to make the html input field allow to be blank, when i click the submit button on the form view?

the  idea is when I click the submit button, the input is a must to key in something else the behind code is unable to run, I am using the asp.net and the button is the asp button not html button

http://s15.postimg.org/wtl7xtuyx/myinputpic.png

I want to allow the new password can be blank

Comment: when your english is as poor as that it is extra important to include screenshots and examples of what is happening and what you expect  and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clearing fields is what you want, use .reset() method.

```
document.getElementById("YourFormName").reset();
```

A working fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4fpk2z9o/

I may comprehend it wrongly as I do not really understand what do you want.

**Update (To disable html 5 form validation) :**

Add `novalidate=''` or `<form action="yourform.asp" novalidate>` to your form.

Comment: no clearing field, is want to allow blank when I click button, when I click button, the input value is a must

Comment: Are you getting an error in your ASP side, because at HTML side, you are able to submit blank fields.